# parquet-cascading- can not be used as sink for parquet

Tags: cascading, parquet

We are trying to convert a text file into a parquet file in hfs location. 
But facing an issue in creating  the sink and getting below exception. Please assist.

## **CODE SNIPPET:**

public static final Fields INPUT_FIELDS = new Fields("sample_int", "sample_str", "sample_date","sample_deci", "par_key");
Scheme sinkScheme = new ParquetTupleScheme(INPUT_FIELDS);
Tap sink = new Hfs(sinkScheme, parqOutputPath);

Pipe assembly = new Pipe("namecp");
assembly = new Each(assembly, new UnpackTupleFunction());

## Flow flow = new Hadoop2MR1FlowConnector().connect("namecp", inData, sink, assembly);

## **EXCEPTION:**

Exception in thread "main" cascading.flow.planner.PlannerException: tap named: 'namecp', cannot be used as a sink: Hfs["ParquetTupleScheme[['sample_int', 'sample_str', 'sample_date', 'sample_deci', 'par_key']->[ALL]]"]["/user/cloudera/parquet_hive_cascade"]
    at cascading.flow.planner.FlowPlanner.verifyTaps(FlowPlanner.java:379)
    at cascading.flow.planner.FlowPlanner.verifyAllTaps(FlowPlanner.java:266)
    at cascading.flow.planner.FlowPlanner.buildFlow(FlowPlanner.java:169)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:456)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:445)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:421)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:270)
    at cascading.flow.FlowConnector.connect(FlowConnector.java:215)

============================================================================

## **SAMPLE DATA:**

1|abc-xy|14-12-25|12.34|20150101
2|fbcxy|14-12-05|2.4|20150201
3|fbscxy|14-11-05|0.422|20150301
3|fbscxy|14-11-15|2.0|20150301

## 4|fbscxy|14-11-30|42|20150401